# QNX 6.6 to QNX 7.0 Neutrino difference

Tags: migration, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

As title says, I would like to the Kernel difference between QNX6.6 Neutrino to QNX7.0 Neutrino. I meant the APIs related to OS specific. I want to migrate a platform from QNX6.6 to QNX7.0, so would like to know, is there any difference between QNX6.6 and QNX7.0 irrespective of the platform we use.

Please any quick clarification would be of any help.

Comment: Maybe read the release notes?

Comment: I am not sure about the release notes.. I got a one.. but whether that one is released right after 6.6 release is a question and still unclear.